# Sorting query result to associative array with optional keys

Tags: php, sorting, associative-array

Using PHP I am running a query on my database and as a result I get a data-set with optional values. An example:

```
Result:
Array
  (
     [0] => Array
       (
         [attribute_1] => Red,
         [attribute_2] => Car,
         [name] => Sportscar
       )
     [1] => Array
       (
         [attribute_1] => Red,
         [attribute_2] => ,
         [name] => Rose
       )
  )
```

I want to format the resulting Data as such:

```
Array
   ( 
      [Red] => Array
         (
            [Car] => Array
                  (
                    [0] => Sportscar
                  )
         )
      [0] => Rose
   )
```

So that I could access the Sportscar by

```
$array['Red']['Car'][0];
```

And the Rose by

```
$array['Red'][0]
```

This will make it easier to output the data with a nice little foreach loop.

of course the actual case is a bit more complex with a lot more values etc but this example demonstrates the principle.

The problem is that I can't think of a proper way to format the data efficiently. Not necessarily recursive but at least not one million if and elses would be nice.

Any ideas?